# Modify and update a cell in excel using python based on a users input

Tags: python, excel

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

#This is how to make a new dataframe and transfer it to a demo excel file in sheet1

# dataframe Name and Age columns
df = pd.DataFrame({'#': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'Name': ['John Doe', 'Jamie Perkins', 'Daryl Walker', 'Dave Mann'], 'Age': [10, 20, 30, 45]})

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('demo.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()


#Up next is how to add new information to a sheet1


# new dataframe with same columns
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'#': [5, 6, 7, 8], 'Name': ['E','F','G','H'], 'Age': [100,70,40,60]})
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('demo.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')

# try to open an existing workbook
writer.book = load_workbook('demo.xlsx')

# copy existing sheets
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in writer.book.worksheets)

# read existing file
reader = pd.read_excel(r'demo.xlsx')

# write out the new sheet
df2.to_excel(writer,index=False,header=False,startrow=len(reader)+1)

writer.close()


#What I want to figure out is how to modify a name based on input from user and update the information to the existing cell in the excel file

num = input("Which name do you want to change?(choose a number)\n")

number = int(num)

if number == 1:
    nName = input("What is the new Name\n")

    df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Name': [nName]})

    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('demo.xlsx', engine ='openpyxl')
    writer.book = load_workbook('demo.xlsx')
    reader = pd.read_excel(r'demo.xlsx')
    df3.to_excel(writer,index=False,header=False,startrow=1)
    writer.close()

elif number == 2:
    nName = input("What is the new Name\n")

    df4 = pd.DataFrame({'Name': [nName]})

    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('demo.xlsx', engine ='openpyxl')
    writer.book = load_workbook('demo.xlsx')
    reader = pd.read_excel(r'demo.xlsx')
    df4.to_excel(writer,index=False,header=False,startrow=2)
    writer.close()

elif number == 3:
    nName = input("What is the new Name\n")

    df5 = pd.DataFrame({'Name': [nName]})

    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('demo.xlsx', engine ='openpyxl')
    writer.book = load_workbook('demo.xlsx')
    reader = pd.read_excel(r'demo.xlsx')
    df5.to_excel(writer,index=False,header=False,startrow=3)
    writer.close()

elif number == 4:
    nName = input("What is the new Name\n")

    df6 = pd.DataFrame({'Name': [nName]})

    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('demo.xlsx', engine ='openpyxl')
    writer.book = load_workbook('demo.xlsx')
    reader = pd.read_excel(r'demo.xlsx')
    df6.to_excel(writer,index=False,header=False,startrow=4)
    writer.close()

elif number == 5:
    nName = input("What is the new Name\n")

    df7 = pd.DataFrame({'Name': [nName]})

    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('demo.xlsx', engine ='openpyxl')
    writer.book = load_workbook('demo.xlsx')
    reader = pd.read_excel(r'demo.xlsx')
    df7.to_excel(writer,index=False,header=False,startrow=5)
    writer.close()

elif number == 6:
    nName = input("What is the new Name\n")

    df8 = pd.DataFrame({'Name': [nName]})

    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('demo.xlsx', engine ='openpyxl')
    writer.book = load_workbook('demo.xlsx')
    reader = pd.read_excel(r'demo.xlsx')
    df8.to_excel(writer,index=False,header=False,startrow=6)
    writer.close()

elif number == 7:
    nName = input("What is the new Name\n")

    df9 = pd.DataFrame({'Name': [nName]})

    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('demo.xlsx', engine ='openpyxl')
    writer.book = load_workbook('demo.xlsx')
    reader = pd.read_excel(r'demo.xlsx')
    df9.to_excel(writer,index=False,header=False,startrow=7)
    writer.close()

elif number == 8:
    nName = input("What is the new Name\n")

    df10 = pd.DataFrame({'Name': [nName]})

    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('demo.xlsx', engine ='openpyxl')
    writer.book = load_workbook('demo.xlsx')
    reader = pd.read_excel(r'demo.xlsx')
    df10.to_excel(writer,index=False,header=False,startrow=8)
    writer.close()

else:
    print("Wrong input please try again")
```

I know how to make a new dataframe and transfer it to a demo excel file and call it sheet1. I also know how to append new data into a current existing excel file.

What I want to know is how to modify a cell based on input from user and update the information to the existing cell in the excel file. Using the if statements seems like it works but does not update the excel file. I also want to know if there is an easier way around this besides using a lot of else if's. I only want to change one name at a time.

I'd appreciate any help I can get!

Edit: Thank you for the feedback on the syntax unfortunately I'm still running into the error of the excel file not updating there is no error on the terminal yet there it is not updating.

Comment: In each branch you write df2, rather than the new df with the input name.

Comment: Thank you for the syntax error catch! Unfortunately, when I run the program the excel file still does not update with the new name I am inputting. Ill send a screenshot of the error I am receiving in the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I ran your code, I was getting a new worksheet "Sheet11" with the updated data, so you need to specify the sheetname and startcol in your to_excel.

If your excel is small, you can modify the DataFrame and rewrite the entire sheet each time. Below I concatenate the 2 DataFrames into one then modify from there.

```
#What I want to figure out is how to modify a name based on input from user and update the information to the existing cell in the excel file
df = pd.concat([df, df2], ignore_index=True)
print(df)

num = input("Which name do you want to change?(choose a number)\n")
number = int(num)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('demo.xlsx', engine ='openpyxl')

if number in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]:
    nName = input("What is the new Name\n")
    df.loc[df['#']==number, 'Name'] = nName
    print(df)
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)
    writer.close()
else:
    print("Wrong input please try again")
```

EDIT: If you just want to update the one cell, this works:

```
#What I want to figure out is how to modify a name based on input from user and update the information to the existing cell in the excel file
df = pd.concat([df, df2], ignore_index=True)
print(df)
num = input("Which name do you want to change?(choose a number)\n")
number = int(num)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('demo.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
#Need to load the workbook, or it overwrites all data on the sheet.
writer.book = load_workbook('demo.xlsx')
#Evidently need to load the sheet names in order to write to an existing sheet
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in writer.book.worksheets) 

if number in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]:
    nName = input("What is the new Name\n")
    df.loc[df['#']==number, 'Name'] = nName
    print(df)
    df.loc[df['#']==number, 'Name'].to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False, header=None, startrow=number, startcol=1)
    writer.save()
else:
    print("Wrong input please try again")
```

Does the requirement for `writer.book = load_workbook('demo.xlsx')` imply that the writer is just rewriting the entire book each time?

Comment: Thank you for the reply! To answer your question, no, the only requirement is to rewrite one of the names that was given in the original eight to a different name. It does not need to be rewritten each time.

Comment: You are welcome. My question was related to how openpyxl works. I think that the answer is that unless you load the workbook, it has to write the entire thing as it does not know the structure to inert into. Similar to the requirement to load the sheets to write to an existing one. Can you accept the answer if it is correct?

Comment: Yes, it makes sense i'm not sure how to convert the dataframe into a workbook though

Comment: The second snippet does not do what you want?